# Sessions, multiple PHP files, die() and authentication flags

Tags: php, session, authentication, post

I have a login built thusly:

There is admin.php
This script checks if `$_SESSION["auth_flag"]` is defined as "true" (string")
If not, then admin.php include()'s login.php

login.php is a generic login page module, which sends an xhttp request with the input to do_login.php

If the credentials are correct then do_login.php sets `$_SESSION["auth_flag"]` to true and then does `die("0")`;

After all that login.php checks the return of do_login.php If it is "0" then it does a location.reload() via javascript reloading the page (admin.php)

However after this - `$_SESSION["auth_flag"]` is not set.

Does die() unset changes made to $_SESSION during that same script?

Will post relevant snippets of code on request since there are no errors in error.log besides

```
[Sun Feb 07 20:45:28.957347 2016] [:error] [pid 1593] [client 89.201.9.253:18390] PHP Notice:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /mnt/disk/html/dev/prefs.php on line 3
[Sun Feb 07 20:45:28.957766 2016] [:error] [pid 1593] [client 89.201.9.253:18390] PHP Notice:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /mnt/disk/html/dev/login.php on line 3
```

Comment: you probably have included files which all/or some contain `session_start();` in there which explains the notices.

Comment: Yeah, but those calls are all ignored, as indicated by the error log. Removing those calls does not solve the problem.

Comment: *"Does die() unset changes made to $_SESSION during that same script?"* - `die()` stops everything dead in its tracks. If you have code below that, then that won't get evaluated. You'll need to post all relevant code.

Comment: in answer to your "does die break stuff" - no - everything before it will execute - you will need to post some code as your logic is fine as described :)

Comment: die does not change session until you unset the session until you unset the session and destroy the session. die only breaks your script from going any further. If die is called before session is registered, then yes session remains unset.